# Pie chart using chart.js and asp.net web Service (asmx)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, ajax, chart.js

I have a static `pie-chart` created using `chartJS` and now I want to provide the data and labels from an asp.net webservice(asmx) to show the actual data that comes from the database but I don't know how to do that. 
**This is the Static Chart Code**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
        <title>Pie Chart</title>
        <script src="../../dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../utils.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="canvas-holder" style="width:40%">
    <canvas id="chart-area"></canvas>
</div>

 <script>
   var config = {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                data: [420,576,812],
                backgroundColor: [
                    "#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2", "#3cba9f"
                ],
                label: 'Labels'
            }],
            labels: [
                'iPhone',
                'Windows Phone',
                'Samsung'
            ]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true
        }
    };

    window.onload = function () {
        var ctx = document.getElementById('chart-area').getContext('2d');
        window.myPie = new Chart(ctx, config);
    };
 </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**The Data I want to Show**
 `Phone` as `Chart Label` and `Amount` as `Chart-Data`

```
-------------------------
-Phone         -  Amount-
-------------------------
-iPhone        -   323  -
-Windows-Phone -   210  -
-Samsung       -   860  -
-------------------------
```

**The Web Service that fetch the data**

```
    [WebMethod]
    public void GetTotalPhoneSales()
    {
        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
        List<TotalSales> totalSales = new List<TotalSales>();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetTotalPhoneSales", con)
            {
                CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            };
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                TotalSales PhoneSale = new TotalSales
                {
                    Amount = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Amount"]),
                    Phone = rdr["Phone"].ToString()
                };
                totalSales.Add(PhoneSale);
            }
        }
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(totalSales));
    }
```

**Expected output**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may call the web service method from Jquery Ajax function and return the values.
What you have to change is

1) Change the return type of your web method to string[][](Array of string Arrays:because we need to return two arrays)

2) Call this web method with the help of Jquery ajax function and in the success function assign the data and label options with respective arrays received from the jquery ajax call.
[documentation of Jquery ajax function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: i think i have provided enough for you to start something. try and get back to here with your code. everyone here will surely help you. but if you ask someone to code for you , i am sorry but SO is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 0):

**Finally I solved it like this**

```
 <script>

   //make an ajax call to the webservice
   //then use `chartlabel` as label and `chartData` as Data

    var chartLabel= [];
    var chartData= [];

    $.ajax({
        url: 'TestService.asmx/GetTotalPhoneSales',
        method: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {

            $(data).each(function (index, item) {
                chartLabel.push(item.Phone);
                chartData.push(item.Amount);
            });

        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert(err);
        }
    });

   var config = {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                data: chartData,
                backgroundColor: [
                    "#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2", "#3cba9f"
                ],
                label: 'Labels'
            }],
            labels: chartLabel
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true
        }
    };

    window.onload = function () {
        var ctx = document.getElementById('chart-area').getContext('2d');
        window.myPie = new Chart(ctx, config);
    };
 </script>
```

**Note:** Its better to assign the `backgroundColor` programmatically, so that when new items are added to the database then those items will not show up with `same color` on the chart by default.
thanks for the hint @Gagan Deep

Comment: I am so glad you did it yourself.